# Menus intermittently take two clicks

Tags: 10.10, gnome, menu

Intermittently, when I left-click on the Applications/Places/System menus, the first click does nothing, and it takes a second click to drop the menu. I've also noticed that hiarchial menus sometimes don't show their expanded menus unless I move the mouse pointer away to another menu item, and then come back into the hiarchial menu. And lately, I've even noticed that in some applications, menus are acting the same way. Any ideas? Cheers, Al

Comment: Is Compiz (i.e. desktop effects) running?

Comment: I have had this same problem, ever since upgrading to 10.10.

Comment: this seemed to be a problem for me...then i found that if i moved the mouse a small bit after the click it worked okay.  probably the fact that i'm using compiz and nvidia closed source, but i want opencl/cuda support so...

Comment: It's very old question and it seems the problem is gone. Even if it is not, we can't support 10.10 now. I'm closing this as Of-topic